# aJavascript scientific calculator input error

Tags: javascript, calculator, trigonometry

Working on a calculator with basic sin and cosine functions.

Code in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/C9VcE/

Getting an error where I can only enter one character for the input.

Also currently sin function

```
function call_func(sin) {
        output=Number (numberone, numbertwo)
        document.getElementById('equation').value =output; 
    }
```

seems to have issues where until I press 'Clear" the calculator won't change values.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wow, that's one messy fiddle!

Comment: @elclanrs Sorry about that, will clean up now.

Comment: @elclanrs Should be better. jsfiddle did some odd things with the body formatting.

Comment: Nice try but jsfiddle has many panels and you don't need the boilerplate code. Check out how a clean fiddle looks like: http://jsfiddle.net/C9VcE/2/

Comment: Ah, good point @elclanrs. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code lies in the getnumber function definition.

Please change the code as specified below and give a try.

```
function getnumber (number) {
            var val = document.getElementById('equation').value;
            document.getElementById('equation').value = val.toString() + number;

            if(numberone=="") {
                numberone=number;
            /*document.getElementById('equation').value =numbertwo; */
            } else {
                numbertwo=number;
            /*document.getElementById('equation').value =numberone; */
            }

        }
```

Comment: Thanks @Ramesh for the quick reply. This tweak does something odd with the input. At no point will it let you add/subtract/multiply numbers.

The good news, the input does allow more than one character with this tweak. [http://jsfiddle.net/C9VcE/3/]

Comment: @Muhamad Aktar: You have to parse the value of text field into integer again. The value of text field is always string.

Comment: As per @elclanrs comment, cleaner jsfiddle version.  http://jsfiddle.net/C9VcE/6/

Answer (score 0):

I've seen your code. You need to put this line

```
document.getElementById('equation').value =document.getElementById('equation').value+number;
```

But then you need to trim and convert this string to number correctly